# Ionization Energy equal to single electron energy

Tags: orbitals, ionization-energy

The ionization energy represents the amount of energy needed to detach an electron from an atom or molecule. Is it accurate to state that this electron possesses an energy precisely equivalent to the ionization energy?

Comment: And after ionization the energy of an electron is zero ?  An electron does not possess an ionization energy (I) but lies on a state with - I in energy. After ionization it keeps its intrinsic energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ionization energy is the energy deficit the bound electron has with respect to the energy of a free electron in rest.

So, if the ionization energy of a $\ce{H}$ atom is $\pu{13.6 eV}$ and if we take as the reference the energy of a free electron as $\ce{0 eV}$, then the energy of an electron in H atom is $\pu{−13.6 eV}$.

It is consisting of (both mean values) $\pu{−27.2 eV}$ of potential energy and $\ce{+13.6 eV}$ of kinetic energy.

To answer the question, providing just the ionization energy will release the electron from the bound with (approximately) zero kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to also state the reference state to which you compare the energy content.

What you can state is that you used the ionization energy to detach the electron from atom (where it was previously bounded).

Imagine an electron being detached from an atom in a gravitational field. This electron might have much more energy in the gravitational field than the ionization energy you just used.

Comment: But if the energy of the electron consists only of kinetic energy + potential energy through coulomb interaction with the other electrons and nuclei, the statement is correct?

Comment: Gravitational potential energy would be negligible enough. And besides, a significant wave-particle duality of an electron will complicate it further.